# People sitting versus one another

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find number of ways to place 8 people around circular table so two specific persons sit versus one another.
Correct answer is $6!$. I tried placing two of them versus one another, and then I have exactly $3$ persons between them. Those $3$ we can choose on $6\choose3$ ways, but I am not able to get $6!$.

Comment: What does "sit versus one another" mean?

Comment: After choosing the people, you need to decide who sits where.

Comment: In contrast to, facing one another..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the people are Alice and Bob. After sitting them you can count six places (clockwise) from Alice to Bob (3 to Bob, 3 from Bob to Alice). Sitting the 6 people in these 6 seats is exactly $6!$ options.

For your method: you need to choose the 3 that will sit between then (from Alice to Bob CW) then sit them, then sit the rest: ${6 \choose 3}\cdot 3! \cdot 3!$

Answer (score 1):

The number of circular permutations of six people is $\frac{6!}{6}=5!.$ Then according to your defintion of "versus" meaning opposing one another, there are $6$ such ways to place the remaining two people in between the other six people. So the answer is $6\cdot 5!=6!.$